# How do I compare two files using Eclipse? Is there any option provided by Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

How do I compare two files using Eclipse?

(Currently I am using [WinMerge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinMerge).)

Comment: If someone needs to compare a file with an external file (not in a workspace), then there is a command `Compare with Other Resource`. For example, one can use it through quick access command search (shortkey `Ctrl+3`).

Answer (score 385, accepted):

To compare two files in Eclipse, first select them in the *Project Explorer / Package Explorer / Navigator* with control-click.  Now right-click on one of the files, and the following context menu will appear. Select **Compare With / Each Other**.

[image]

Comment: If the option "Each Other" doesn't appear in the menu "Compare with", go to Preferences > Capabilities > Advanced and enable Team > Core Team Support, then restart Eclipse.

Comment: And if it is disabled, just select two or more files... :)

Comment: If the files are too far apart in Project Explorer to select them easily, try a Ctrl+H File Search for *filename1*, *filename2* and click on them in the search results.

Comment: For the same file in multiple locations, you can also use `Open Resource` (`Ctrl + Shift + R`): type the name, select the desired locations, then right-click and select `Show In` -> `Package Explorer`. From there, right-click the displayed result and you'll be able to select `Compare With` -> `Each Other` =)

Comment: One important improvement: in *Window > Preferences > General > Compare/Patch* select *Ignore white spaces*. The quality of the comparison increases greatly (in my opinion).

Comment: Eclipse file comparator works pathetic for complex differences in 2 files. Rather I found notepad++ comparator much better, gives correct differences as right places. But it has its own set of issues. Wondering if there is any better file comparison Plugin for Eclipse!!!!!

Answer (score 43):

Just select all of the files you want to compare, then open the context menu (Right-Click on the file)  and choose Compare With,  Then select each other..

Answer (score 15):

If one or both of the files you wish to compare isn't in an Eclipse project:

1. Open the Quick Access search box

   - Linux/Windows: Ctrl+3
   - Mac: ⌘+3
2. Type *compare* and select *Compare With Other Resource*
3. Select the files to compare → *OK*

You can also create a keyboard shortcut for *Compare With Other Resource* by going to *Window* → *Preferences* → *General* → *Keys*

Comment: No window opens for me in latest eclipse and fresh workspace, anyone experience the same? Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)

Comment: Same here on 2020-03 (4.15.0) Build id: 20200313-1211. I can bring up the _Compare With Other Resource Option_ but nothing happens when it is selected.

Comment: @DanielSokolowski: A file has to be selected in the Project Explorer or Package Explorer, then the dialog will open - and you can select any external file outside of the workspace. Not exactly intuitive...

Answer (score 6):

Other than using the Navigator/Proj Explorer and choosing files and doing 'Compare With'->'Each other'... I prefer opening both files in Eclipse and using 'Compare With'->'Opened Editor'->(pick the opened tab)...
You can get this feature via the AnyEdit eclipse plugin located here (you can use Install Software via Eclipse->Help->Install New Software screen):
http://andrei.gmxhome.de/eclipse/

Comment: THIS just saved my life! Thanks!

Comment: AFAICR used to be part of default installation. Thx for digging up this old gem !

Answer (score 3):

**Compare with Other Resource – The Easy Way using Eclipse (no additional plugin required)**

To assign a keyboard shortcut to the feature, go to **Window > Preferences > General > Keys,** look for the command Compare with Other  Resource and assign it to a keyboard shortcut of your liking. See How to manage keyboard shortcuts in Eclipse for more details on configuring shortcuts.

Tip: Alternatively, you could press Ctrl+3 (for Quick Access) and search for Compare with Other Resource. This way you don’t have to configure a shortcut but you’ll have to search for the command every time in Quick Access.

Once the shortcut is assigned, you need to select the source file from the Package Explorer, Project Explorer or Navigator. The easiest way to do this from an open editor is to assign a shortcut to instantly show the file in the Package Explorer or, if it’s not open, to open it quickly using the keyboard.

[image: Select_File_In_Package_Explorer]

Now press the keyboard shortcut you assigned to Compare with Other Resource and the following (non-modal) dialog should appear:

[image: Compare With Each Other Dialog]

Troubleshooting: If the dialog doesn’t appear, it’s probably because you haven’t selected a file in either the Package Explorer or another view that allows file selection. Make sure a file is selected and make sure you haven’t selected the class in the Package Explorer rather than the actual Java file.

Now you can select the second file in the Package Explorer and drag and drop it onto the dialog. Click OK and the comparison editor should display, comparing the two selected files.

[image: Comparison Editor]

Tip: See the post on using shortcuts for common SVN commands for tips on how to navigate the comparison editor with the keyboard.

Comparing External Files
Using the Compare with Other Resource dialog, you can compare a workspace file with an external file or even compare two external files with each other.

Comparing a workspace file with an external file is easy: Once you’ve opened the dialog from a selected file, instead of dragging and dropping another workspace file, tick External File in the Right pane and then Browse to a file on your filesystem.

[image: comparing external]

To compare two external files, you have to start the dialog again from a selected workspace file (choose an arbitrary file). Once open, select External File in the Left pane and Browse to your file then do the same for the Right pane.

Please refer this page for more details: http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2013/09/19/compare-two-workspace-or-external-files-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 2):

If your compairing javascript you might find it not displaying.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509820

Here is a workround...

> - Window > Preferences > Compare/Patch > General Tab
> - Deselect checkbox next to "Open structure compare automatically"

Answer (score 0):

If you have Beyond Compare installed, the ContextQuickie eclipse plugin has an option to enable it to be selected from the context menu displayed when you right-click a file.

Install from:

https://github.com/ContextQuickie/ContextQuickie/wiki/Installation

After install, activate Beyond Compare menu items via Window->Preferences->Context Quickie->check 'Enable Beyond Compare'.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind the **Compare with other Resource** command to a key via **Window > Preferences > General > Keys** (as described by the answer from bmaupin and barani-r), change the **When:** option to **In Dialogs and Windows**. It seems this will open the dialog even if you don't have a file selected, but if you do have a file selected/in focus, it'll be pre-filled as the first file in the comparison.

(I suggest an easy key bind to remember is a combo like Alt + "=".)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).