# Extend or configure Eclipse compare files functionality

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse has [built in functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623564/how-do-i-compare-two-files-using-eclipse-is-there-any-option-provided-by-eclips) for comparing files, but how can I configure that functionality? Say I create a new file type and want an external program do perform the diff. How do I set that up?

Can I create an Eclipse plugin to add my own plugin for handling file comparisons? Or perhaps that is the answer to the first question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  may want to look at the [EMF Compare Project](http://www.eclipse.org/emf/compare/) which helps build compare editors for EMF models. If you don't have an EMF model for your file type, you can either create one or look through the source code of EMF Compare to see how it works.

The [developer guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF_Compare/Developer_Guide) explains how to use the code to write your custom viewers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [plugin integrating Beyond Compare into Eclipse](http://beyondcvs.sourceforge.net/). As it is open source, you might get a clue by looking at its sources.