# Is there a 'diff' API in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to get the difference between two files in my eclipse plugin program. Is there such a "diff" API I can use?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623564/how-do-i-compare-two-files-using-eclipse-is-there-any-option-provided-by-eclips

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse Compare editor provides an API that plugins can use - see the section [Compare support](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fcompare_beyond.htm) in the Eclipse help.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using **org.eclipse.compare** plug-in. Eclipse uses it to compare files inside eclipse.