# Eclipse - quicker "compare with each other"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I am using **Eclipse Kepler** and want to:

- Quickly compare two files (key binding would be great)
- ...with identical names
- ...in different projects
- ...within the same workspace

---

Now, the process I know consists in:

- Selecting both files in the file explorer
- `Right-click`ing one of them
- `"Compare with..."`
- `"Each other"`

(See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623564/how-do-i-compare-two-files-using-eclipse-is-there-any-option-provided-by-eclips)).

This works fine, of course.

However, it's also incredibly tedious when you're dealing with large projects - essentially you get to scroll up and down the package list until you find the right files.

It helps to link the editor with the file explorer, and `Ctrl-Shift-R` both files before, so the package trees are open and one of the file's already selected, but that's not nearly quick enough.

I also tried to "select" those files by `Ctrl-Shift-Click`ing the tabs in the editor, hoping it would select both in the file explorer, but no luck.

Is there any feature or workaround I don't know about, to help speed this up?

Comment: Do the projects also have the same structure? Like, different versions of the same project? Not an answer to the question, but there are tools other than Eclipse that can compare entire directory hierarchies, e.g. Meld for Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files have the same name, you could *search* for the files (*Search -> File...*). Leave the 'Containing Text' blank and specify (part of) the name of the files. Both files will appear in the *Search* View where you can select and right-click them and select *Compare with -> Each other*.

Not sure whether this is as fast as you'd like it to be, but its certainly faster than manually looking for the files in the Package Explorer view.