# CLI: Compare two files with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I want to compare two files that are not in the workspace.

For example, in VSCode, I can do this:

`$ code --diff file1 file2`

Is there any way to do it with eclipse?

**What I've tried**

- I can open individual files with

  - `eclipse.exe "fileName"`
- I understand that this can be done easily via the GUI.

  - [How do I compare two files using Eclipse? Is there any option provided by Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623564/how-do-i-compare-two-files-using-eclipse-is-there-any-option-provided-by-eclips)

Comment: No, Eclipse doesn't provide command line tools.

Comment: You can, though, create them as files in the workspace *linked* to their original locations, select both files, and then right-click Compare them to each other. This most quickly done by dragging them each from the Finder/Explorer into the Project Explorer view.